# How to change background-color on click with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, click, background-color

I have a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/J96nF/7/).

I want to accomplish something similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/jdXUH/1/).

I'm not able to figure out where am I going wrong.

Comment: Whats the actual issue? The bottom ones all work for me.

Comment: @Abhishek How about *not* writing redundant code...

Comment: @Loktar: the bottom 1 i tried 1st, the `demo` is the one that i want to make it work somwthing like bottom 1

Comment: Why do you need all of the ifs anyway? @Abhishek - He means the bottom ones in your demo work fine.

Comment: You have to select jQuery in the fiddle, not MooTools. Also, for @Vidas's and @Richard's sakes: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/passcod/zyJwV/), and [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/passcod/aGPgx/).

Comment: It seems to work in jsfiddle now, after i selected jQuery, but in my project it is not working

Comment: @passcod - Yeah, thats how I would have done it.

Comment: There are references in your Fiddle to functions that don't exist. You should take a look at the JS console. There are tons of errors. Plus, What's the point having so many onClicks? Your markup could weigh about 25% of what it does and still accomplish the same things.

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. I removed the redundant code, errors might be because it uses a `spry` dataset, which is not available in jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your demos, you is just changing `background-color` of spans, regardless of their `id`, so those ifs are very unnecessary. Just [it](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/J96nF/8/) is working well:

```
$(".AccordionPanelContent span").click(function() {
    $(".AccordionPanelContent span").css("background-color", "white");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but what you meant with this comment?

Comment: Well mr.Saparelli aka *passcod*, as a tech sci guy (YOU) should know that we are all here: **1.** to get some help, **2.** to help, **3.** to be up-down-voted. **4.** To have a good free time. Seeing this comment of yours, you should seriously consider to never become a teacher. Or you are just born genius.

Comment: All of the code works  fine in the demos but my project code is not working may be there is some mistake, that only I can handle, so thanks guys @ErickPetru: you answer was 1st 1 so i'll give it to you. Thanks everyone for helping out

Comment: @Abhishek Simon - Thank you for voting up! Always glad to help! Good luck with that stuff!

Answer (score 1):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/UZmu7/1/)

The code used:

```
$("span[id*='select']").click(function() {
    $("span[id*='select']").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

And a bit of CSS:

```
.selected{
    background:#f00;
}
```

You can see the  `$("span[id*='select']")` , it restricts the selector to only the ID elements that have a name containing the text: `select....`